# User defined iOS interface

Tags: objective-c, user-interface

**Introduction**

I am writing an app where the interface on a screen can vary depending on user input on the previous screen. What I'm trying to do right now is load up x amount of sliders, where I get x from the previous screen. The real issue I'm having is won't each slider I use have to be named and defined? I've thought of a way to do this but I'm not entirely sure how to implement if you could advise me it would really be appreciated

**Pseudo Code**

```
-(void) loadInterface {
    // Set up a frame
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 100.0f, 250.0f, 25.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            [self newSlider]
        // Retrieve info here about the slider and pass it to newSlider
    }

}

-(void) newSlider (info about slider) {

    // Here I need the code to load a slider
    // If I use something like this:
    // UISlider *slider1 = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    // The next time this method is loaded the slider will be overwritten right?

}
```

Comment: What's the maximum number of sliders you expect to have?

Comment: Maybe 5 or 6, the thing is I want to apply this to other custom interface parts that might be more complex

Comment: Is there a way I could maybe name them according to string? that would solve the issue I think

Comment: Please define "name them according to string"

Comment: Something like:
NSString *myString = @"SliderName";
UISlider *myString = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];

Comment: Just use array. Add the UISlider in NSMutableArray.

Comment: Erm I'm not sure if I know what you mean because the redefinition of the variable doesn't make sense and won't compile, but if I understand correctly you should perhaps store the sliders in a dictionary, with the key being a string with the name of the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an NSMutableDictionary to keep track of all your sliders, although maybe you do not need that at all.

In `newSlider` you create a slider and you should add it to some view (I assume `self`) through

```
[self addSubview:slider];
```

All sliders thus created will appear at the position where you created them and will not disappear unless you remove them from the view.

You could take this snippet as an example of how you can create a slider:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

If you define correctly `frame`, you can make all of your sliders align nicely in your UI.

When a slider action is carried through by the user, the `sliderAction:` method is called, which has an argument referring to the slider:

```
- (void)sliderAction:(UISlider* slider) {
   ...
}
```

so you know exactly which slider was actioned and this is generally enough to handle the action.

In any case, as I said, if you want to keep track of all the sliders, add them to a NSDictionary at the moment of creation:

```
[self.sliderDict setObject:newSlider forKey:@"nth-slider-name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need new variables for each slider, because the scope of the `UISlider` instance you use in your `newSlider` method is limited to that method. Meaning the variable will be free for use once the program exits the method.

You should also pass which slider it is to that method, this can then be used to position it and to give the view a tag for later use:

```
-(void) loadInterface {
    // Set up a frame
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 100.0f, 250.0f, 25.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        [self newSlider:i]
        // Retrieve info here about the slider and pass it to newSlider
    }

}

-(void) newSlider:(int)sliderNumber {
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, sliderNumber * 100, 320, 50)];
    slider.tag = sliderNumber;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
}
```